# How to disable file sharing and enable printer sharing via configuring Windows 10 group policies?

Tags: windows, file-sharing, group-policy, gpo

How to disable file sharing and enable printer sharing via configuring Windows 10 group policies?

I try "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=No
Bash" in command prompt but it disabled two of them.